# How do I interpret this bash output redirection with '<'?

Tags: bash, sh

I have this Bash command `{java command} > /dev/null 2>/var/log/server.log < /dev/null &` and I'm having a hard time understanding what this means.

I know that...

1. `> /dev/null` means to stdout to a void
2. `2>/var/log/server.log` sends errors to /var/log/server.log
3. `&` means to run in the background

But what is `< /dev/null`? Also, am I understand the redirection correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` means redirection of `stdin`, i.e, standard input.

`< /dev/null` means input source has nothing, and `stdin` is always `EOF`.